# Plumber returns Error in makeTcpServer, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: r, plumber

I am trying to run simple code with `plumber`

```
library(plumber)
plumber::plumb("simple_function.R")$run(port = "80")
```

It returns error:

```
Running plumber API at http://127.0.0.1:80
Running swagger Docs at http://127.0.0.1:80/__docs__/
Error in makeTcpServer(host, port, private$appWrapper$onHeaders, private$appWrapper$onBodyData,  : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=integer].
```

It worked this morning just fine. It stopped after installed Docker and build a couple of containers.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define your port as a numeric

```r
library(plumber)
plumber::plumb("simple_function.R")$run(port = 80)
```